# how can we make sure all the promises gets resolved before running next cycle of loop

Tags: typescript, async-await, es6-promise

how can we make sure if there are multiple promises(like 5-10) inside a loop running 100 times, how can we make sure all the promises gets resolved before running next cycle of loop.

lets say i am running a loop

length of items array = 100;

```
for(i in items)
{
  if(i=0)
  {
     await getData1();
  }
  if(i=1)
  {
     const a = await getData2();
     const b = await getData3(a);
  }
}
```

if for the first time  = 1, it is running. How can i make sure that before running for i=2, it should resolve all the promises for i=1.
And shouldn't accumulate unresolved promises.

Comment: `await` would guarantee promises are resolved.

Comment: You want Promise.all([...])

Comment: @zerkms : await will resolve my promise but I want that promise to be resolved first and then move to next line , if not resolved then it should wait till then but after resolving only it should move to next line.

Comment: @linda : Promise.all will resolve the promise but how can we tell  it the sequence in which it should resolve it, cz output of my first function is the input of second function.

Comment: @SunnySinha that's what your code would do: a next iteration would only start after previous promise was resolved.

Comment: what do you want exactly?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `async` module, check the [documentation](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html)

```
let async = require('async');
async.eachSeries(items, async(item)=>{
       await getData1();
       const a = await getData2();
       const b = await getData3(a);

},()=>{
    console.log("finish")
})
```

Comment: You shouldn't re-assign a javascript keyword as a variable. I would use "asyncModule" or similar.

Comment: can you explain more and what's the problem about my answer? @LoganDevine

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi You are assigning the variable `async` to the value `require('async')`. `async` is a keyword in JS (used as `async function ...`) and it's never a good idea to assign a keyword as a variable (shouldn't even be possible). `async` as a keyword is used as `async function ...` (a modifier).

Comment: It’s a popular module, check the documentation or search async npm

Comment: How is this 3rd party library better than their original code?

Comment: because 40M is downloaded every week async module@zerkms

Comment: it's based on documentation in https://www.npmjs.com/package/async @LoganDevine